# 180 degree rotation of .dv clips

Tags: macos

Is there any fast way to rotate .dv movie clips by 180 degrees? I need to process them in Final Cut Pro, but a 180 degree rotation (when used in a multiclip) causes them to require rendering. Any way to do batch processing, even if it takes time, would be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to find a good solution to do this on the MAC, and myself came across [AVI Synth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) for Windows.  It is a scripting form that allows for DV editing (you will probably need the [Cedocdia](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Cedocida_DV_Codec) codec vfw)  You can quickly create a test using the new [rotate function](http://avisynth.org.ru/rotate/rotate.html). (example in link)  You can quickly write up a batch to process hundreded of files if necessary with this example.  There are all kinds of plugins for editing, and I use it for removing interlacing and steadying camera shots.  It works nicely.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that in a VirtualBox it'll work nicely, too.